# Is Hall conductivity and transverse conductivity same things?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, terminology

I wonder if there is any difference between these two terms. Is transverse conductivity always equal to Hall's conductivity?

I am asking in the context of the thermal and electrical conductivities of a material.

Answer (score 1):

If referring to *electrical* (not thermal) conductivities, then yes they are the same thing.

Though the term *Hall* usually pops up when dealing with the Hall effect (classical or quantum) meaning the transverse conductivity is dominated by the effect of an external magnetic field.